# call ssjs within javascript-onbeforeunload

Tags: xpages

I'm not very used to xpages and webprogramming and I'm stuck here with a problem for a few days now.

Is there any way to call a server side java script within the javascript-onbeforeunload-event? What I have to do is to delete a notesdocument in a notesview when the user leaves the page.

f.eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = callSSJS;
    function callSSJS(){
      here I'd like to call a ssjs - f.eg. 
         var vw:NotesView = database.getview("anyview");
         var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getDocumentByKey("123");
         doc.remove(true);
     }
</script>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be realized with the *execOnServer* method from Jeremy Hodge: http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC

First create a event in your XPage:

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onunload" id="onUnload" submit="false">
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:executeScript>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                var vw:NotesView = database.getview("anyview");
                var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getDocumentByKey("123");
                doc.remove(true);
            }]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:executeScript>
    </xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Then add the CSJS output script block to your XPage:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlockOnUnload">
    <xp:this.value>
    <![CDATA[

        var executeOnServer = function () {

            // must supply event handler id or we're outta here....
            if (!arguments[0])
                return false;

            // the ID of the event handler we want to execute
            var functionName = arguments[0];

            // OPTIONAL - The Client Side ID that you want to partial refresh after executing the event handler
            var refreshId = (arguments[1]) ? arguments[1] : "@none";
            var form = (arguments[1]) ? XSP.findForm(arguments[1]) : dojo.query('form')[0];

            // OPTIONAL - Options object contianing onStart, onComplete and onError functions for the call to the
            // handler and subsequent partial refresh
            var options = (arguments[2]) ? arguments[2] : {};

            // Set the ID in $$xspsubmitid of the event handler to execute
            dojo.query('[name="$$xspsubmitid"]')[0].value = form.id + ':' + functionName;
            XSP._partialRefresh("post", form, refreshId, options);

        }

        window.onbeforeunload = function(){

                        if( ! dojo._xhr )
                           dojo._xhr = dojo.xhr;

                        dojo.xhr = function ( args, ioArgs, addArgs ){
                           ioArgs["sync"] = true;
                   ioArgs["failOk"] = true;
                           return dojo._xhr( args, ioArgs, addArgs );
                        }
                        executeOnServer('onUnload');
                    };
    ]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

The last line is the hook for the unload method which calls the server side event to delete the document.

**EDIT:**

Added a dojo ioArgs for a sync call and a better failure handling.

Comment: That's a great solution. I was thinking about `xhrGet` and a new XPage to execute the SSJS.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it helped me a lot. but unfortunately the event is not triggered, when I open another xpage, only if I open another webpage, f.eg. www.google.com. 

I've two custom controls. one for the layout (extlib application layout) and one for the notes document. I've tried to put the code in the panel-tag of the cc for the notesdocument, but it didn't get fired. So I've put the code in the xpage, which combines the two cc's. As mentioned before, the code is executed when opening another webpage but not when I open another xpage in the same database.

Comment: @Martin: What do you mean with "open another xpage"? how do you open it / navigate to this page?

Comment: I prefer xe:jsonRpcService from the Extension Library.

Comment: @Sven: the script isn't executed as long as I stay on the same server. I tried opening the page through the onui-menu and by directly entering the url in the adress bar.

Comment: @D.Bugger: Same Problem. The event "onbeforeunload" only fires when I completely leave the server.

Comment: @Martin: This is a completely different question. If your event is not fired, how should this trigger some server side code?!?

Comment: @Sven: Your're right. The weird thing is that a return is executed all the time, even if I stay on the same server. I guess that onbeforeunload isn't reliable at all so I'm not going to implement any documentlocking with xpages at this time. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Martin Have you tried with Dojo? http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/addOnUnload.html or dojo.addOnWindowUnload.